# ROS compatibility with PowerBot

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm a beginner to ROS and robot control in general. Are the libraries provided by ROS compatible with the PowerBot from mobilerobots.com ([PowerBot](http://www.mobilerobots.com/ResearchRobots/PowerBot.aspx))?

Thanks.
R.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199239/ros-compatibility-with-powerbot/) by [RND](https://answers.ros.org/users/21074/rnd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2014-12-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes there are drivers for the powerbot: http://robots.ros.org/powerbot/

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0